# Artifactory looses track of files in a generic storage

Tags: artifactory, nfs

I am trying to adopt Artifactory for our CI\CD. And I'm faced with quite weird issue. I run Artifactory in docker container with a NFS share mounted inside docker which is being used as Artifactory data folder. Everything works just fine until some time when Artifactory fails to serve uploaded binaries without any reason (404 file not found error from my web browser, when I click "Download" button). And it get back to working state when I go to NFS share server and try to view a folder containing the binary using Web UI (Synology provides NFS). I've assumed that it's time bias makes this happen, but after I've set up NTP on both servers it still fails. How Artifactory identifies binaries and converts readable urls to its internal hash based file paths?

Comment: Actually, (when artifactory's lost binary named 04cc490bbfa4a6dfc2c8d55f3e57ffbcbca05676) I can just
`docker exec -it 3919a3126257 ls /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/filestore/04`
to get Artifactory able to serve files again.

Comment: The problem still there with Artifactory ver 7.3.2. The issue resolves even if I just view the file on the host where NFS is served from.